# API call on application close javafx

Tags: java, api, asynchronous, javafx, freeze

I have built a simple javafx application to run some operations on the network interfaces of a pc. During application close, I need to make an API call to a remote server to perform some cleanup tasks. The number of API calls can vary from 0-20. I have overridden the stop method and tried to make the API call there before closing the application but since I'm using the same thread, this is causing the application to freeze while closing. Windows,by default waits for 5 seconds until it decides the application is not responsive and gives an error. Is there any other way to tackle this problem?
Ps: I also have a small http server running inside my application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ... I'm using the same thread ...

This is both the problem and the solution.

When stopped, the JVM **waits** for all non-daemon threads to finish. This also gives you the mechanism you are looking for. You just need to run a separate thread in which to do the necessary processing.

JavaFX allows you to intercept the application thread stop (the `Application::stop()` method) in which you can start the new thread. The disadvantage of this approach is that calling `Application::stop()` is not guaranteed (you can stop the application with `System::exit()` for example).

```
public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        stage.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() throws Exception {
        super.stop();

        new Thread(() -> {
            // API call ...
        }).start();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

A better option is to use `Runtime::addShutdownHook()` to start the corresponding thread.

```
public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);

        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(() -> {
            // API call ...
        }));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I went with the shutdown hook approach.